# Cannot write to XML file in another computer from my program

Tags: c#

When I write to an XML file, an exception occurs: "Cannot access file because it used by another process". How can I fix that problem?

Answer (score 4):

You can use things like "Process Explorer" (easy to find) on the machine in question to double-check which process is locking a file. If you **don't** own the competing process, the best you can do is ask the operator to kindly close the file and/or app that is blocking you.

Assuming you *do* you manage the other process that is locking the file? The most common cause of unexpected locks is files not being closed cleanly. Check that you are **religiously** closing all file handles after use, ideally using `using` so that they are closed even in error conditions - for example:

```
using(Stream dest = File.Create(path)) {
    // write to dest
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely this means another program has this file locked.  Try saving in another location and make sure you're properly disposing objects used to write to the file when you're done writing.  Also double-check you have proper permissions to write this folder (try creating a basic text file there)

Keep in mind that your program may be running with different permissions than what you are logged in with.

Answer (score 0):

The XML file that you are trying to write to will be currently open by any other process [file opened] and will be in a locked state. You cannot modify a file that has been locked.

Close any file handles that are currently using the resource.